# Django how to make family relations

Tags: python, django

I wonder how can we make a relations between 2 users, which can be applied in reverse.
The goal is when creating an object via `django admin` to add relation between 2 users and create the opposite of it in the second user, the sex of the user is very important for the reverse connection.

I have tried to create the reverse of it when creating the object but then it crashes because it tries to recreate the object again and again.

**models.py**

```
SEX = (
    ('m', 'Male'),
    ('f', 'Female'),
)
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"



RELATIONS = (
    ('mother', 'Mother'),
    ('daughter', 'Daughter'),
    ('father', 'Father'),
    ('son', 'Son')
)


RELATIONS_REVERSE = {
    'mother':{
        'm':'son',
        'f':'daughter'
    },
    'father':{
        'm':'son',
        'f':'daughter'
    },
    'son':{
        'm':'father',
        'f':'daughter'
    },
    'daughter':{
        'm':'father',
        'f':'mother'
    }
}

class UserRelation(models.Model):

    User_1 = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name="User_1", null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="User_2", null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relation = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=RELATIONS, null=False, blank=False)


    #THIS DOES NOT WORK!
    # def save(self):
    #     UserRelation.objects.create(
    #         User_1= self.User_2,
    #         User_2= self.User_1,
    #         relation= RELATIONS_REVERSE[str(self.relation)][self.User_2.sex]
    #     )
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import User, UserRelation

class UserRelationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserRelation
    fk_name = 'User_1'

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UserRelationInline
    ]


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify the save function as follows:

```
def save(self, first_save=True):
    if first_save:
        UserRelation(
            User_1=self.User_2,
            User_2=self.User_1,
            relation=RELATIONS_REVERSE[str(self.relation)][self.User_2.sex]
        ).save(first_save=False)
    super().save()
```